# Cant seem the get my dropdown menu to work, spent hours looking through this and a tutorial, but I cant seem to get it right

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012, razor, input

I'm trying to get a dropdown menu along side my other text inputs, I've been tracking a music store tutorial for this specific feature, but I cant seem to get mine to work. I've been revising my code and comparing for hours but I cant see my errors, If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my controller code:

```
    // GET: /Default1/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.CardTypeId = new SelectList(db.CardTypee, "CardTypeId", "Type");
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Default1/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Card card)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Cards.Add(card);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        ViewBag.CardTypeId = new SelectList(db.CardTypee, "CardTypeId", "Type",  card.CardTypeId);
        return View(card);
    }
```

My models that I have:

Card.cs

```
 namespace ActualPayment.Models
 {
   public class Card
   {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public CardType CardType { get; set; }
    public int CardTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public int SortCode { get; set; }
    public int SecurityCode { get; set; }
    public int ExpirationDate { get; set; }

  }
}
```

CardType.cs

```
namespace ActualPayment.Models
{
    public partial class CardType
    {
        [Key] public int CardTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

    }
}
```

CardTypes.cs

```
namespace ActualPayment.Models
{
    public class CardTypes : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CardPayment>
   {
       protected override void Seed(CardPayment context)
       {
           var cardType = new List<CardType>
           {
               new CardType { Type = "Visa/Delta/Electron" },
               new CardType { Type = "Master Card/Euro Card" },
               new CardType { Type = "American Express" },
               new CardType { Type = "Solo/Maestro" },
               new CardType { Type = "Maestro" },
           };
        }
    }
}
```

CardPayments.cs

```
namespace ActualPayment.Models
{
   public class CardPayment : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<CardType> CardTypee { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Card> Cards { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my view:

```
@model ActualPayment.Models.Card

@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"     type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Card</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardTypeId, "CardType")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CardTypeId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardTypeId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardNumber)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SortCode)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SortCode)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SortCode)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SecurityCode)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SecurityCode)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SecurityCode)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExpirationDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpirationDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpirationDate)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: The problem might caused by StyleSheets did you check them too?

Comment: There is a drop down, however its tiny and has nothing in it. I tried changing the css to match that of the tutorial there, but it hasn't made a difference unfortunately.

Comment: So where is the code of your menu in your view and controller?

Comment: Are they not already there posted or do you want the entire controller class as well? That has the standard scaffold controls.. but I can if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's nothing wrong with the code.

Chrome capture for posted values[image: Chrome posted value capture]

value at action [image: value at controller action]

Did you mean the CardTypeId is not getting populated??

Comment: Yeah, there is a drop down, but it has no values in it, Its just a little box with an arrow and only has a blank that can be selected, would give an image but I cant..

Comment: When user lands on create screen there are no values in dropdown? did u check is there are values in ViewBag.CardTypeId = new SelectList(db.CardTypee, "CardTypeId", "Type"); 

viz db.CardTypee

Comment: In my controller I have:             ViewBag.CardTypeId = new SelectList(db.CardTypee, "CardTypeId", "Type", card.CardTypeId);
            return View(card);
        }, but Im not 100% what you mean, pretty amateur at mvc3 and VS

Comment: ViewBag.CardTypeId = new SelectList(db.CardTypee, "CardTypeId", "Type"); means you gonna setup your downdrop list's value from CardTypeId.

In your View,

 @Html.DropDownList("CardTypeId", String.Empty)

means MVC will look into ViewBag/ViewData to populate your dropdown values, string.Empty is default selection.

Can you confirm ViewBag.CardTypeId has values by putting break point on it?

Comment: Is that what I want to set it up with, or should it be done with Type... which is in the CardType class?

Comment: if db.CardTypee doesn't have value, you gotta populate it.

Comment: How would I do this and do you mean with the values I have in my CardTypes class ie visa/...